# manual compostion of two functions

Tags: racket

I try to make my own (compose) function, but I can't get through it.

It needs to work as follow:

let's call that function "manual" - manual needs to take two arguments, and it has to compose them in a way that later we can call our manual like this: `((manual func1 func2) 1)` (so the output of the manual needs to be a procedure)

so if the func2 multiplies input by 2, and func1 raise it to the third power, then output of `((manual func1 func2) 1)` should be `8` (`( 2*1)^3`)

I tried to write function like this:

```
(define (manual func1 func2) 
    (func1 (func2)) ; or f(g), or many other combinations of parenthesis
)
```

but unfortunately I couldn't came with idea of composing those two.

So I guess it needs to be a bit more abstract/complex than just some manipulation with parenthesis.

Comment: This might be due to copying from your editor to this website, but you entered braces instead of parentheses and are using variables f and g while your inputs are func1 and func2.

Comment: also it is worth thinking about which arguments can the resulting composition accept

Comment: I edited the post so there are only func1 and func2 now, and parenthesis instead of braces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want a function, `manual`, that accepts two functions, `f` and `g` -

```scm
(define (manual f g)
  ...)
```

It should return a function, call it `composition` -

```scm
(define (manual f g)
  (define (composition ...)
    ...)
  composition)
```

When `composition` is applied to an argument, `arg`, it should return a result of `f` applied to `arg`, where `g` is applied to `f`'s result -

```scm
(define (manual f g)
  (define (composition arg)
    (g (f arg)))
  composition)
```

Let's test it -

```scm
((manual
  (lambda (x) (+ x 1))
  (lambda (x) (* x 2)))
 3)
```

```scm
8 ; (3 + 1) * 2
```

It would be nice if `composition` didn't require a name. `lambda` allows us to define a nameless, anonymous procedure -

```scm
(define (manual f g)
  (lambda (arg)
    (g (f arg))))
```

If I want to make the composition accept multiple arguments, I can use `apply` to apply `f` to all `args` -

```scm
(define (manual f g)
  (lambda args
    (g (apply f args))))
```

```scm
((manual * add1) 10 20)
```

```scm
201 ; (10 * 20) + 1
```

If I want `manual` to accept any number of functions, I can rewrite the composition to apply all of them in sequence using a [left fold](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29) -

```scm
(define (manual f . more)
  (lambda args
    (foldl (lambda (f x) (f x))
           (apply f args)
           more)))
```

```scm
((manual * add1 add1 add1 add1 add1) 10 20)
```

```
205 ; (((((10 * 20) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1
```

Above special behaviour is given to the first function in the sequence. If I want to make `manual` generic, I can ask the caller to handle the specialized behaviour -

```scm
(define (manual . funcs)
  (lambda (init)
    (foldl (lambda (f x) (f x))
           init
           funcs)))
```

```scm
((manual
  (curry apply *) ; specific behaviour
  add1
  add1
  add1
  add1
  add1)
 (list 10 20)) ; multiple arguments collected in a list
```

```scm
205 ; (((((10 * 20) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1
```

@PeterWinton points out that a [typical compose function](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._compose%29%29) will apply the functions in *right-to-left* order. The `manual` procedure we wrote above applies them *left-to-right*. It's worth knowing the difference and what's considered common in practice. Writing `manual` to reflect this behaviour remains an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Nice step-by-step answer. Two comments: 1) it is more common to say that a function is applied to an argument, rather than an argument being applied to a function. 2) The question requires the second function (`g`) to be applied first, as do [typical composition functions](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._compose%29%29).

Comment: I appreciate the comment Peter. I made some edits with your comment in mind :D

Answer (score 1):

When you call `(manual f g)` you want to obtain a function that you can call with more arguments:

```
((manual f g) 0 1 2 3)
```

Let's simplify first this requirement and only accept one argument:

```
((manual f g) 0)
```

In order to obtain a function of one parameter, you write a lambda form:

```
(lambda (v) ...)
```

So you are probably going to write the following:

```
(define (manual f g)
  (lambda (v) ...))
```

If think you should be able to fill the remaining code.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't see it.